# Invisible icons while dragging if icon size is larger than 55

Tags: debian, xfce, icons

I am running Debian 9 / Xfce and I need to setup larger icons on the desktop.
If I make the icons size larger than 55 they become invisible while dragging them to a new position or target. Is there any known workaround to prevent this behavior?

Comment: try stable-backports in debian sources.list, no problems on sid.